# Why does a a torus knot parameterization invert the sign of the z values?

Tags: trigonometry, knot-theory, parametrization

The [torus knot page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot) contains the following (p,q)-torus knot parametrization:\begin{aligned}x&=r\cos(p\phi )\\y&=r\sin(p\phi )\\z&=-\sin(q\phi )\end{aligned}
where\begin{aligned}
r=\cos(q\phi )+2\end{aligned} and \begin{aligned}
0<\phi <2\pi\end{aligned}

What motivates the use of the additive inverse of the computed sine function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard torus that a torus knot lies on has a coordinate system given by a *longitude* $\lambda$ and a *meridian* $\mu$.

[image: Torus with a longitude and a meridian]

The standard torus bounds a solid torus, which has a core circle.  Give it an orientation, for example so that it has linking number $+1$ with the oriented $z$-axis.  The longitude is a copy of the core circle pushed off to the boundary torus in such a way that the loop bounds a disk in the exterior (capturing the idea that $\lambda$ does not "wrap around" the torus about the minor circumference).  The meridian is an oriented loop in the torus that has linking number $+1$ with the core circle and that bounds a disk in the interior of the solid torus (capturing a similar idea of not "wrapping around" longitudinally).

If you look at $\mu$ in the $XZ$ plane, you'll see that it is a circle that is oriented clockwise.  That is why there is a minus sign.

[image: Meridian in the XZ plane]

I found it helpful to think about
\begin{align*}
x&= r = \cos(q\phi)+2\\
y&= 0\\
z&=-\sin(q\phi)
\end{align*}
which is the parameterization while being rotated about the $Z$ axis to keep the parameterized curve on the $XZ$ plane.

Homologically, a $(p,q)$ torus knot is $p[\lambda]+q[\mu]$.  That is, it goes $p$ times around in the longitudinal direction while going $q$ times in the meridian direction.

Comment: Thank you @Kyle Miller for the visuals; they helped to illustrate your explanation. If the orientation of the red circle were counterclockwise, i.e. if there weren’t a minus sign, would the set of points the equations indicate no longer constitute a torus knot? If the points wouldn’t be a torus knot, which part of the definition of a torus knot would fail to apply to them?

Comment: @bblohowiak It would still be a torus knot (a torus knot is just a knot on a torus).  But, it would be the $(p,-q)$ torus knot, which is different from the $(p,q)$ torus knot in general.